# Graph Theory: Are Infinite Trees Planar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, trees

Graph theory: Are infinite trees planar? I think countable trees are, but not uncountably infinite trees, apparently. How does one construct such a tree?

Comment: Draw the $x$-axis.  Your vertices are the integers, and your edges are $(n,n+1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Relevant: [Can there exist an uncountable planar graph?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712013/can-there-exist-an-uncountable-planar-graph)

Comment: Oh wait I was confused. Is it just that there isn't enough "room" to put anything? So if there was a higher cardinality analogue of R^n then the graph might be "planar".

Comment: It is easy to construct a class of such graphs starting with a root and correspond the childs  to an interval and so on - representation is some kind of Sierpinski triangle. But going to 2nd step childs things gets more complicated.

Comment: So if we have an infinite tree the cardinality of the continuum (vertex set)...

Comment: If you have a tree with a vertex set big enough (for example $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$), then it cannot be injected in the plane.

Comment: Yes, intuitively any higher cardinality tree cannot be embedded into plane, I don't see how to construct something like that.